# How to use Node packages without internet connection?

Tags: linux, node.js

We have been using Node in production for a while now and I’m curious to know other companies deploy Node packages in their prod systems.

Do you have your own Node repos like Maven or you build package on a machine with internet access and transfer it to offline machine?

Comment: Generally the build process is what requires the dependencies, so where do you plan to do your build, and what are the policies you must follow there? Its pretty common for build to occur on a build server, and then the deploy pipeline places it on the destination machine. Prod servers shouldn't usually have build tools installed, unless they are part of your build architecture, so it doesn't really matter if the prod server is connected or not, as long as your release pipelines can reach it.

Comment: I come from maven background where I can have an exe jar with all deps. I can take that jar and deploy it on any machine with jre. I dont see that is the case with npm. My first problem is: how do I create a single artifact with all deps? Can I .tar it? Zip it maybe? Today I ran in to another issue. My primary machine is windows so I `npm install` a package which gave me a `.exe` file. Our servers running CentOS cant use it. If I had a centralized repo...I can build on CentOS directly.

Comment: that sounds like an entirely different issue. no idea what you are installing or why it is an exe. anyway, you need the dependencies on the system performing the build, and after you have built the program, the instance of it you deploy to centos has all the dependency files already in it.

Comment: > you need the dependencies on the system performing the build

Comment: Ignore above. Cant edit that. :( You are right. The `.exe` is a different issue. But I found the answer to my OP.

Answer (score 1):

I found `npm-bundle` that does exactly what I was looking for. It generates a `.tar.gz` (like a maven `.jar`) with all deps that I can deploy anywhere. It says `npm-bundle` is deprecated in lieu of `npm install` but `npm install` does not do what I expect it to do.